# Minor memory allocation question C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
int main() {


  char **k;
  char *s ="abc"; 
  char *b ="def";

  *k = s;


}
```

//Why does this produce segmentation fault? Shouldn't everything be store on the stack without any problems?

Comment: What exactly do you think `*k` should be? What would `k` point to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` has no defined value yet, so dereferencing it (`*k`) causes undefined behaviour. If you add an initialization, i.e. `k = &b;`, `*k = s;` will work afterwards.

Comment: so char *s automatically has defined value? What would be the correct way of using k?

Comment: @Mark: You could say `k = &s`.

Comment: No, but you initialized both `s` and `k` so they have a valid value. Remember, dereferencing a pointer means *read the value of the pointer, treat it as memory address and access this memory address*. If `k` has no initial value, `*k` basically reads at whichever location the arbitrary bit pattern in `k` happens to point at.

Comment: but how come when I tried k = new char* I could direct using *k = s?

Comment: @Mark: Because `k` has a value then. In your code example you didn't initialise `k`, then you dereferenced it, therefore accessing memory that probably doesn't belong to you, landing you in undefined behaviour land.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I hope I don't get beaten up with with any slight error... here is my attempt to explain it as fully as I can.

With an ordinary char* it will point to a char.

with a char** it points to a pointer that points to a char.  That *k value is on the heap and not the stack.

i.e. like this:

```
stack (1)    heap (2)   heap or ... (3)
+-----+    +-----+     +----+
|char*| -> |char*| ->  |char|
+-----+    +-----+     +----+
```

Now char*'s are not really strings but they are treated as blocks of contiguous printable characters in memory that are terminated by a null or zero byte.  So the string would be stored and be referenced at (3)

So to fix your code you'll want to allocate space for a char* (not a char).

i.e. put

```
k = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

before the line

```
*k = s;
```

Not that it's a good code, But it shouldn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

[Alexander is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566204/minor-memory-allocation-question-c/6566212#6566212), you're dereferencing `k` with `*k = s;`. Your initialization of `char *s="abc";` may look the same, but it is syntactic sugar for the longer: `char *s; s="abc";`